# Can structs map to tables in CTP Code First?

Tags: entity-framework

Is there a way to map struct to tables in Code First. I looked everywhere and everyone seems to be talking about POCO classes to start with. I couldn't find anything about structs.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Structs are not supported.

Comment: Why not? What would be the argument against enabling that?